# ASP.NET AJAX PageRequestManager EndRequestHandler pass argument from server

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax

I'm wondering if there is a way to modify the arguments retrieved by the EndRequestHandler to include a boolean flag (set on the server side during a partial update).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
"ScriptManager instance".RegisterDataItem(this, "value");
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301423.aspx